# Обработка ошибок

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Делаю обработку ошибок (403, 404, 500). Для этого сделал отдельный контроллер и представления.

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    // GET: Error
    public ActionResult General(Exception exception)
    {
        return View("Exception", exception);
    }

    public ActionResult Http404()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Http403()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

В `Global.asax.cs` прописал следующий метод:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();

    log.Error(exception);

    Response.Clear();
    var httpException = exception as HttpException;

    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");


    if (httpException != null)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();

        switch (Response.StatusCode)
        {
            case 403:
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "Http403");
                break;
            case 404:
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "Http404");
                break;
            default:
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "Error");
                break;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "General");
        routeData.Values.Add("exception", exception);
    }

    Server.ClearError();
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    IController errorsController = new ErrorController();
    errorsController.Execute(new RequestContext(
        new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));

}
```

Если я в Url ввожу несуществующий контроллер (пример: `http://localhost:62693/123`), у меня в браузере отображается HTML-код моего "ошибочного" представления (вместо самого представления).

Если же введенного пути в целом не существует, но в нем контроллер указан правильно (пример: `http://localhost:62693/News/123`), то тогда в браузере само представление отображается корректно.

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Какого проведения вы ожидаете?

Comment: @Андрей, я бы хотел понять, почему выдает HTML-код вместо представления, когда в Url ввожу несуществующий контроллер. И как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтоб исправить ошибку, надо просто добавить

`Response.ContentType = "text/html";`

и тогда будет возвращаться представление, а не просто `HTML`.

**Другой способ обработки ошибок.**

**web.config**

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
    <remove statusCode="404" />
    <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Http404" />
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

**Controller**

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult PageNotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Это помогло мне.